# Issue in Facebook oAuth2.0 redirect URI with Angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am adding oAuthentication to my Angular-Java based web application but having a hard time integrating it.

Below is the code where I am doing redirecting for authentication from Facebook oAuth :

```
var redirect_uri="http://localhost:3000/#!/oAuthHandle";
var fbLoginUrl = "http://www.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth?" + "client_id="
                + client_id + "&scope="
                + scope + "&redirect_uri="
                + redirect_uri;
window.location.replace(fbLoginUrl);
```

The **Problem** comes because of (hash)**#** present the redirect URI, instead of Facebook showing the popup for approving or rejecting the access 
to my App, the page gets redirected to https://www.facebook.com/oAuthHandle,

> **This page isn't available** 
>   **The link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been
>   removed.**

I then tried removing **'#'** in URI with

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

but now the problem comes when my browser redirects to the **redirect_uri**, Angular Routes doesn't detect the `oAuthHandle` state and **404 error comes**.

Searched a lot on many websites including SO as well but didn't find a satisfactory answer.

**Note:** I am using `ui-router` and I think there is already an issue while refreshing the page with html5Mode on whose solution is here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/372 which says you have to fix something on the server, but in OAuth redirection, i can't control Server side code.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I've had problems testing things like this on localhost in the past. If you can redirect through apache/nginx then html5mode works better. [nginx conf example](https://gist.github.com/cjus/b46a243ba610661a7efb)

Comment: hey @Razzildinho thanks, will you please go through the ui-router issue i mentioned in the post, the problem is not only  on redirecting the issue is that even with  html5Mode on if I hit URL without using `ui-sref` it gives `404` exception